# Did Shinji activate EVA Unit 01's Berserk Mode?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion, rebuild-of-evangelion

During the fight with Zeruel when EVA Unit 01 loses all power, Shinji enters somewhat of a demonic state, stating the Angel give Ayanami back or face the consequences. After he says this, EVA Unit 01 reactivates and enters its berserk mode, thus starting its "awakening" process.

Now, this got me thinking, did Shinji himself activate EVA Unit 01's berserk mode in the heat of battle or was the timing just right for both EVA Unit 01 and Shinji?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the original anime series, it was established that the berserk mode can't be triggered voluntarily. Moreover it was at least strongly hinted that the "berserk mode" is in fact

> the manifestation of motherly love and protection, as it always activated when Shinji's life was in immediate danger.

In the Rebuild continuity, there is the so-called "beast mode" that can be activated by the pilot, but it is only ever shown working for Unit-02, not for Unit-01. Therefore it is at least very improbable, if not outright false, that Shinji could have willingly activated this mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think berserker mode is activated by

> the soul of Yui Ikari. She is inside the Eva and activates her full power when she feels Shinji is in risk.

Comment: from my understanding Rebuild has yet to establish the whole loved one's souls in the Eva's thing and the OP is referring to events from the Rebuild series